Basic Design-Code question with Visual Studio/C#
[Visual Studio version 17.8.3 -- Community 2022]
I have used Visual Studio quite a bit to write VB programs.  I am now attempting to use it to write C# programs.  (I have a background in Java as well, so the coding isn't an issue.)  I am having trouble with the designer-code interplay.
I am getting a designer error when I don't think I should.  Is there a "proper" way to entirely delete an event-handler function if it is unwanted?
Scenario:
(1) In Designer, I add a label and a button to a form.
(2) I accidentally double-click on the label instead of the button when adding an event-handler
(3) I go to the code and delete the auto-added Click function code for the label.  (Which shouldn't have any code tied to it.)
(4) I go back to the designer and it has produced a "Design-Time" error.  (The name 'label1_Click' does not exist in the current context )
I can use undo to put the function back and the error goes away.  (Then I'm stuck with an empty function.)  I can delete the label, then delete the code and all is okay.  (But, if I have spent some time setting properties for the label, deleting it because I accidentally mis-clicked is painful.)

Try the following:
VS 2022:
Open Solution Explorer

In VS menu, click View
Select Solution Explorer (Ctrl+Alt+L)

Open Properties Window

In VS menu, click View
Select Properties Window (F4)

Open Desired Form in Form Designer (ex: Form1.cs)

In Solution Explorer, right-click desired form (ex: Form1.cs).
Select View Designer (Shift+F7)


Remove Desired Event Handler (ex: Click)
Option 1:

In the Form Designer (ex: Form1.cs [Design]), click the desired control (ex: label1) to select it
Click 
Scroll down to desired event (ex: Click)
Right-click desired event (ex: Click)
Select Reset

Option 2:

In Properties Window, select desired control (ex: label1) from the drop-down
Click 
Scroll down to desired event (ex: Click)
Right-click desired event (ex: Click)
Select Reset

Note: If the event handler contains code, then the event handler code may not be removed from the code view (Solution Explorer => right-click Form1.cs => View Code). If you've already removed the event as described above, then the code for the event handler can be deleted manually.

Optional - Verify the event subscription has been removed

In Solution Explorer, click the arrow next to the desired form (ex: Form1.cs) to expand it
Click <form name>.Designer.cs
Double-click Windows Form Designer generated code to expand the region (or the arrow to the left of the text)

Note The code in <form name>.Designer.cs should (almost) never be modified manually and definitely not without having a backup of one's solution.

The option to go back to the designer, select item, go to properties, and remove the event handler works.  It is a bit non-intuitive, or at least deviates from VS things I was able to do in Visual Basic.  VB allowed the programmer to simply remove the subroutine w/out breaking the GUI.  Ah well.  New habits to learn.  Thanks!

A little bit simpler method I use whenever this happens to me. This will work In all the versions you reference in your question: After deleting the auto-added code, look at the Error List window (I believe this opens by default usually at the bottom of your code window). It will reference the missing event definition. Simply double-click the description line and it will bring you straight to the errant line of code in the designer. Delete the line and your Design-time error is gone.
